# How to track mouse position from on page load as well as on mouse move?

Tags: javascript, mouse, mouseevent

I am tracking mouse movements using the following JavaScript:

```
var mouseX = 0;
var mouseY = 0;

document.onmousemove = function (e) {
    mouseX = e.clientX;
    mouseY = e.clientY;
}
```

My problem is that if the mouse hasn't been moved since the page had been loaded, the mouseX and mouseY values both equal 0. How can I get the mouse values when the page is loaded as well as when the mouse is moved?

Comment: I believe you can't know that. But isn't it feasible to drop the first movement and start with the second? E.g. you start with `mouseX = mouseY = null`, and in case they're `null` when `onmousemove` is fired, then just ignore that first case.

Comment: http://docs.jquery.com/Tutorials:Mouse_Position

Comment: By "page load" do you mean when the document is ready or when the window is loaded? Those are two separate cases.

Comment: pimvdb: no that isn't good enough, i need to know where the mouse is even if it hasn't yet moved! I think my solution will be use onload event but loop in conjunction with settimeout loop for if the page isn't fully loaded yet.

Comment: @MarcB that doesn't do it for him either. If you notice, when the page is loaded and the mouse hasn't moved, the values are 0, 0.

Comment: @amaan: you're right. I'd tested by reloading the page, but must've nudged my desk or something. it WAS showing offsets at page load earlier.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The browser doesn't know where the mouse is until it moves.

It's more complicated than just "get me the cursor position". What if there is no mouse (tablet) or what if the mouse is not over the browser window?

For the same reason, you can't get hover events on an item if the cursor is already hovering when the page loads. It takes a mouse movement for those events to fire.

Go to some site, hover over a link that has a hover effect (like underline), refresh the page (without moving your cursor) and you'll see that even though your cursor is hovering over the link, it doesn't get the hover treatment until you move the cursor.

Unfortunately this is a browser-level issue, not a javascript issue.

Comment: Tim Down is right. Clearly some browsers do know where the mouse is, even when it's not moving. No doubt the OS provides a way of getting this information, but sadly the DOM API doesn't do the same.

Comment: @Tim Down: Seems to obsolete? Working in Chrome, Firefox, Opera, IE9 and newer. At least on windows.

Comment: @SuperNova: I think you're agreeing with me if you mean that the hover style is applied after refresh in those browsers. On my Mac, the hover style isn't applied in Chrome or Opera but is in Safari and Firefox.

Answer (score 0):

You can define mouseover event for the document in order to catch the first mouse interaction on page load.