# Change background color on mouse move and page load as well

Tags: javascript, jquery

I found a sample code which is change the background colour of the body when the user moves the mouse, but the first time the page is white. You can't see the changes until you move the mouse.

```
var $win = $(window),
    w = 0,h = 0,
    rgb = [],
    getWidth = function() {
        w = $win.width();
        h = $win.height();
    };

$win.resize(getWidth).mousemove(function(e) {

    rgb = [
        Math.round(e.pageX/w * 255),
        Math.round(e.pageY/h * 255),
        150
    ];

    $(document.body).css('background','rgb('+rgb.join(',')+')');

}).resize();
```

JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/WV8jX/

How can I trigger on load?

Comment: body{
  background:blue;
} in css

Comment: Sorry, maybe I didn't explain properly. I want to use the same color at the first time as well. In this case when you start to move the cursor you gonna jump from blue to pink or red or whatever. On load I need to use the same color when move event. Is it possible?

Comment: pageX and pageY ? how u can get in pageload? I think u have to set default pageX and pageY.

Comment: You can't track the mouse position until the mouse has moved http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8013062/how-to-track-mouse-position-from-on-page-load-as-well-as-on-mouse-move

Comment: Yes, I think it's just not possible to get the position on load

Answer (score 2):

**Working Example:**

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
   getRandomColor();
   RandomMouseMoveColor();
});

function getRandomColor() {
 document.body.style.background = "#"+((1<<24)*Math.random()|0).toString(16);
}

function RandomMouseMoveColor() {
var $win = $(window),
    w = 0,h = 0,
    rgb = [],
    getWidth = function() {
        w = $win.width();
        h = $win.height();
    };

$win.resize(getWidth).mousemove(function(e) {

    rgb = [
        Math.round(e.pageX/w * 255),
        Math.round(e.pageY/h * 255),
        150
    ];

    $(document.body).css('background','rgb('+rgb.join(',')+')');

}).resize();
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use jquery's `$(document).ready()` function, which get's called when the content is loaded to initially set a random background-color (or whatever color you want).

I updated your [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/WV8jX/699/).

Answer (score 0):

```
var $win = $(window),
    w = 0,h = 0,
    rgb = [],
    getWidth = function() {
        w = $win.width();
        h = $win.height();
    };

function colorize(e){  
    rgb = [
        Math.round(e.pageX/w * 255),
        Math.round(e.pageY/h * 255),
        150
    ];

    $(document.body).css('background','rgb('+rgb.join(',')+')');
}

$win.resize(getWidth).mousemove(colorize).resize();
colorize({pageX:0,pageY:0});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use such approach:

```
var $win = $(window),
  w = 0,
  h = 0,
  rgb = [],
  getWidth = function() {
    w = $win.width();
    h = $win.height();
  };

function changeColor(e) {
  rgb = [
    Math.round(e.pageX / w * 255),
    Math.round(e.pageY / h * 255),
    150
  ];

  $(document.body).css('background', 'rgb(' + rgb.join(',') + ')');
}

$win.resize(getWidth).mousemove(function(e) {
  changeColor(e);
}).resize();

$(document).ready(function() {
  var is_loaded = false;
  $(document.documentElement).bind("mouseover", function(e) {
    if (!is_loaded) {
      is_loaded = true;
      changeColor(e);
    }
  });
});
```