# Javascript mouse coordinates without event

Tags: javascript, events, mouse

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to get the mouse position without events (without moving the mouse)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2601097/how-to-get-the-mouse-position-without-events-without-moving-the-mouse)

Is it possible to get the mouse current coordinates without any kind of event?

Only Javascript! No jQuery...

Comment: You can get them on the mouseMove event, but not without an event.

Comment: Nope - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2601097/how-to-get-the-mouse-position-without-events-without-moving-the-mouse

Comment: @Fluidbyte: if you find a duplicate question, you can flag it so that users with 10k rep can vote to close from the 10k tools page. This makes closing duplicates swifter and easier for everyone. :-)

Comment: I already flagged my own question...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, such thing is impossible with javascript only and without events.

Answer (score 0):

It is not possible, neither with plain javascript, nor with jQuery's help. You need at least a `mousemove` event.