# How can I get the mouse position on an HTML5 canvas when canvas is fullscreen?

Tags: javascript, canvas, fullscreen

The following code works perfectly while the canvas is not fullscreen.

```
    let canvas = document.querySelector('canvas');
    let ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');

    document.addEventListener('mousemove',e=>{
        let br = canvas.getBoundingClientRect();
        let mouseX = e.clientX - br.left;
        let mouseY = e.clientY - br.top;
    });
```

However, after `canvas.requestFullscreen()` variables `mouseX, mouseY` do no longer represent the mouse's position on the canvas. 
Is there any way to get the mouse's position relative to the canvas?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [JavaScript: incorrect mouse coords (pageX and pageY in fullscreen mode)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42132146/javascript-incorrect-mouse-coords-pagex-and-pagey-in-fullscreen-mode)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After a long time I finally found a solution.

```
var FULLSCREEN = false;
document.onfullscreenchange = () => {FULLSCREEN = !FULLSCREEN};
// Keep Track of when Screen 

var mouseX=0,mouseY=0;

function map(v,n1,n2,m1,m2){
    return (v-n1)/(n2-n1)*(m2-m1)+m1;
}

doucment.addEventListener('mousedown',e=>{
        var x,y;
        var element = e.target;
        let br = element.getBoundingClientRect();
        if(FULLSCREEN){
            let ratio = window.innerHeight/canvas.height;
            let offset = (window.innerWidth-(canvas.width*ratio))/2;
            x = map(e.clientX-br.left-offset,0,canvas.width*ratio,0,element.width);
            y = map(e.clientY-br.top,0,canvas.height*ratio,0,element.height);
        } else {
            x = e.clientX - br.left;
            y = e.clientY - br.top;
        }
        mouseX = x;
        mouseY = y;
});

// Unfortunately this only works if the element is touching the top and bottom of the screen
// In other words, the ratio between the width and height of your screen must 
// be greater that the ratio of width to height for your element
```

Comment: I can't believe this is necessary, but I haven't been able to come up with anything less ridiculous for something as simple as "where on the canvas did the person click", so here we are...  Thank you for chasing this down.

Comment: Thanks, this is exactly the problem I faced and this code works!  That is, it works in Firefox but not in Chrome.  I will try and see what is making it work differently between them (unless someone knows already....?)

Comment: It is frightening that this level of hackaroni is necessary but you're a life saver. A small addition: the resulting mouseX and mouseY need to be multiple by the value of window.devicePixelRatio on HDPI screens, in case you are using the Canvas track of using different values for width/height and CSS scaling to accomodate for HDPI crispness.