# Is there a way to tell Chrome web debugger to show the current mouse position in page coordinates?

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome, debugging

I often debug my javascript code using the Chrome web debugger. In the elements tab, hovering over an element show a tooltip with a few pieces of information, including the width and the height of that element.

Sometimes, I need to see the page coordinates of the current mouse position. But it seems the debugger does not display this kind of information.

So, is there a way to add it? Like an extension or maybe there are other options?

**EDIT**

Using the accepted answer I could add the following bookmarklet and have exactly what I wanted:

```
javascript:document.onmousemove = function(e){var x = e.pageX;var y = e.pageY;e.target.title = "X is "+x+" and Y is "+y;};
```

Answer (score 181, accepted):

You could type this into the console,

```
document.onmousemove = function(e){
var x = e.pageX;
var y = e.pageY;
e.target.title = "X is "+x+" and Y is "+y;
};
```

This will give you mouse position on mouse move in the element tooltip.

Comment: Nice, but it destroys all the log. And if you remove the clear() statement, then it clutters the log with zillion position messages. Is it the best we can have?

Comment: Ok try the above, i changed it to log it to the title. :)

Comment: What about this?  

    `document.onmousemove = function(e)  
    {  
     document.title = "X: " + e.pageX + " - Y: " + e.pageY;  
    };`

Comment: As a note to followers, this answered "used to" destroy the log but was edited and now only gives you a nice little tooltip if you let your mouse cursor hover in any location long enough.

Comment: Working fine Nice solution to avoid unusal installing extensions

Comment: @Heitor Unfortunately, Chrome doesn't show the document title in its window. No title? Ugh.

Answer (score 57):

Combining [ppsreejith](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1405711/ppsreejith)'s [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12888676/4106215) with [JHarding](https://stackoverflow.com/users/920297/jharding)'s [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8993124/4106215) with Chrome 70+'s [Live Expressions](https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2018/08/devtools#watch) you can get constantly updating `(x, y)` coordinates without filling up the devtools console:

Enter this in the console:

```
var x, y; document.onmousemove=(e)=>{x=e.pageX;y=e.pageY;}
```

Enter this as a Live Expression (to create a Live Expression, click on the eye in the top menu of the console).

```
"("+x+", "+y+")"
```

[image]

And this works on SVGs.

Comment: Hint: to create a live expression press the All Seeing Eye icon.
Other than that not being obvious this is the best answer.

Comment: Didn't work for me. Nothing showed up in the Console.

Answer (score 8):

When i need to see the coordinates for my mouse, i use this Chrome addon: 
[Coordinates addon](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/coordinates/bpflbjmbfccblbhlcmlgkajdpoiepmkd/related)

Comment: It is not working in the Debug Mode in chrome or any browser.

Comment: This is a addon for Chrome, so you can't use it in other browers. 
I did just test the addon, and it's still working as it should. It shows the coordinates of your mouse all the time, even if you open the chrome debug mode/ Chrome DevTools.

Comment: @ChandraShekharRam You have to enable it when you want to use it by clicking on the icon in the chrome bar (upper-right). This is a much better solution than writing in the logs.

Comment: I would have voted this up, but it's now a dead link. The extension I found only shows the coordinates when you click it on, instead of on mousemove. Useless.