# How to get the mouse pointer position when onScroll is called?

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs

I have `handleScroll` callback

```
<div  onScroll={handleScroll} >
```

And `handleScroll` is called when the mouse wheel is touched.

```
const handleScroll = (e) =>{
    console.log("handlescroll clientX",e.clientX);
    console.log("handlescroll clientY",e.clientY);
```

However, it doesn't have a mouse pointer position.

So, I think there are two methods.

1 Get the mouse pointer position in the scroll callback

2 Get the mouse pointer position spontaneously (not by callback)

Either way is possible?

Comment: You should add a listener for the `mousemove` event

Comment: Do you want to handle _scroll wheel events_ or _scroll events_? There are other ways of scrolling: with the keyboard, with the scrollbar, or by touch. The [`scroll` event](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/scroll_event) is a generic [`Event`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event); it doesn't contain any information about the mouse. The system might not even _have_ a mouse.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
let lastMouseX = null;
let lastMouseY = null;

const handleMouseMove = (e) => {
  lastMouseX = e.clientX;
  lastMouseY = e.clientY;
};

const handleScroll = (e) => {
  console.log("Scroll event triggered");
  console.log("Mouse position at scroll - X:", lastMouseX, " Y:", lastMouseY);
};

document.addEventListener('mousemove', handleMouseMove);
document.addEventListener('scroll', handleScroll);
```

Use this code to Capture the Mouse Position on Scroll

Comment: THank you for this idea!, storing the last position and re-use them works well.

Answer (score 0):

The only way to get the mouse position is with **events**. There is no way to get it without callbacks.

You can see more here: [How to get the mouse position without events (without moving the mouse)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2601097/how-to-get-the-mouse-position-without-events-without-moving-the-mouse)

Answer (score 0):

You are doing it the right way.

For the second method you can do it without using callbacks.

```
document.addEventListener('mousemove', (e) => {
    console.log("Mouse X:", e.clientX);
    console.log("Mouse Y:", e.clientY);
});
```

Do let me know how it works for you.